# Database Normalization using Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

I have a sample table like below where Course Completion Status of a Student is being stored:

```
Create Table StudentCourseCompletionStatus
(
    CourseCompletionID int primary key identity(1,1),
    StudentID int not null,
    AlgorithmCourseStatus nvarchar(30),
    DatabaseCourseStatus nvarchar(30),
    NetworkingCourseStatus nvarchar(30),
    MathematicsCourseStatus nvarchar(30),
    ProgrammingCourseStatus nvarchar(30)
)
Insert into StudentCourseCompletionStatus Values (1, 'In Progress', 'In Progress', 'Not Started', 'Completed', 'Completed')
Insert into StudentCourseCompletionStatus Values (2, 'Not Started', 'In Progress', 'Not Started', 'Not Applicable', 'Completed')
```

Now as part of normalizing the schema I have created two other tables - `CourseStatusType` and `Status` for storing the Course Status names and Status.

```
Create Table CourseStatusType
(
    CourseStatusTypeID int primary key identity(1,1),
    CourseStatusType nvarchar(100) not null
)

Insert into CourseStatusType Values ('AlgorithmCourseStatus')
Insert into CourseStatusType Values ('DatabaseCourseStatus')
Insert into CourseStatusType Values ('NetworkingCourseStatus')
Insert into CourseStatusType Values ('MathematicsCourseStatus')
Insert into CourseStatusType Values ('ProgrammingCourseStatus')
Insert into CourseStatusType Values ('OperatingSystemsCourseStatus')
Insert into CourseStatusType Values ('CompilerCourseStatus')

Create Table Status
(
    StatusID int primary key identity(1,1),
    StatusName nvarchar (100) not null
)

Insert into Status Values ('Completed')
Insert into Status Values ('Not Started')
Insert into Status Values ('In Progress')
Insert into Status Values ('Not Applicable')
```

The modified table is as below:

```
Create Table StudentCourseCompletionStatus1
(
    CourseCompletionID int primary key identity(1,1),
    StudentID int not null,
    CourseStatusTypeID int not null CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentCourseCompletionStatus1_CourseStatusType] FOREIGN KEY (CourseStatusTypeID) REFERENCES dbo.CourseStatusType (CourseStatusTypeID),
    StatusID int not null CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentCourseCompletionStatus1_Status] FOREIGN KEY (StatusID) REFERENCES Status (StatusID),
)
```

I have few question on this:

1. Is this the correct way to normalize it ? The old table was very helpful to get data easily - I can store a student's course status in a single row, but now 5 rows are required. Is there a better way to do it?
2. Moving the data from the old table to this new table seems to be not an easy task. Can I achieve this using a query or I have to manually to do this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are storing a literal `Not Started` string in every row, then it's not normalized.

Comment: It may have seemed easier before but the reality is that it is not good. What would happen in the old schema if you needed to add another course? You would have to change the table. Moving this might be a bit of a challenge but not too bad. The problem is you should store the ID of Status, not the string value.

Comment: @SeanLange - In the normalized table I am storing StatusID actually (and not the string value). Please see the last table schema in question.

Comment: StudentID in the second insert should be probably 2.

Comment: @VDohnal Correct, edited the question

Comment: The names of your classes are a bit misleading as I see it. `CourseStatusType` should be `CourseType` with values `Algorithm`, `Database` etc. Maybe you have in your database already another table with types of courses, why not re-use it here?

Comment: The number of rows is not usually a relevant/valid concern for data normalization.  Stop worrying about it.

Comment: @SKJ None of your transformations have anything to do with normalization. Why do you think they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vou could also consider storing results in flat table like this:

### studentID,courseID,status

- 1,1,"completed"
- 1,2,"not started"
- 2,1,"not started"
- 2,3,"in progress"

you will also need additional Courses table like this

### courserId,courseName

- 1, math
- 2, programming
- 3, networking

and a students table

### students

- 1 "john smith"
- 2 "perry clam"
- 3 "john deere"

etc..you could also optionally create a  status table to store the distinct statusstrings statusstings and refer to their PK instead ofthestrings

### studentID,courseID,status

- 1,1,1
- 1,2,2
- 2,1,2
- 2,3,3
  ... etc

and status table

### id,status

- 1,"completed"
- 2,"not started"
- 3,"in progress"

the beauty of this representation is: it is quite easy to filter and aggregate data , i.e it is easy to query which subjects a particular person have completed, how many subjects are completed by an average student, etc. this things are much more difficult in the  columnar design like you had. you can also easily add new subjects without the need to adapt your tables or even queries they,will just work.
you can also always usin SQLs PIVOT query to get it to a familiar columnar presentation like 
name,mathstatus,programmingstatus,networkingstatus,etc..

Answer (score 1):

> but now 5 rows are required

No, it's still just one row.  That row simply contains identifiers for values stored in other tables.

There are pros and cons to this.  One of the main reasons to normalize in this way is to protect the integrity of the data.  If a column is just a string then anything can be stored there.  But if there's a foreign key relationship to a table containing a finite set of values then *only* one of those options can be stored there.  Additionally, if you ever want to change the text of an option or add/remove options, you do it in a centralized place.

> Moving the data from the old table to this new table seems to be not an easy task.

No problem at all.  Create your new numeric columns on the data table and populate them with the identifiers of the lookup table records associated with each data table record.  If they're nullable, you can make them foreign keys right away.  If they're not nullable then you need to populate them before you can make them foreign keys.  Once you've verified that the data is correct, remove the old de-normalized columns.  Done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. Sorry I am not getting how it's still just one row ? The equivalent to the first insert statement in old table: Insert into StudentCourseCompletionStatus Values (1, 'In Progress', 'In Progress', 'Not Started', 'Completed', 'Completed') will be 5 Insert statements in the new table. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @SKJ: Why would it be 5 insert statements?  You're still just inserting one record: `INSERT INTO StudentCourseCompletionStatus VALUES (1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1)`  That's one record, not five.

Comment: If you see my modified table schema I have added a column CourseStatusTypeID which is a foreign key to CourseStatusType table. I am not only doing the foreign key for status name but also for CourseStatusType. So the insert statements will be something like below: Insert Into StudentCourseCompletionStatus1 values (1,1,3)
Insert Into StudentCourseCompletionStatus1 values (1,2,3)
Insert Into StudentCourseCompletionStatus1 values (1,3,2)
Insert Into StudentCourseCompletionStatus1 values (1,4,1)
Insert Into StudentCourseCompletionStatus1 values (1,5,1)

Comment: @SKJ: Ah, I missed that.  In that case, yes, if you change your model to separate previously-inline data into separate records then you will insert more records.  Is that such a bad thing?  Will the types of courses ever change?  (Hint: Probably)  If so then you'd likely want to separate them so that your data model can accommodate that.  That's really the point of de-normalization.  The code which uses this can still abstract that behind a single common object which has a collection of courses, so your application modeling might not change (I can't know, it's not in the question).

Comment: @SKJ: If you're asking, "Is it too difficult to insert more than one record into a database table?" then the answer is "No, no it is not."  Weigh that against the difficulty of supporting a system which is tightly coupled to a finite set of pre-defined courses and you start to see the benefits of de-normalization.

Answer (score 0):

In `StudentCourseCompletionStatus1` you still need 2 associations to `Status` and `CourseStatusType`. So I think you should consider following variant of normalization:

[image: CourseStatus]

It means, that your `StudentCourseCompletionStatus` would hold only one CourseStatusID and another table `CourseStatus` would hold the associations to `CourseType` and `Status`.

To move your data you can surely use a query.